# Subtitles in movies

Tags: grammar

During any movie with subtitles I can observe written actions like "music playing" "engine turns over". What exactly happened to articles? Conjugation verbs? Thanks

Comment: They’re like newspaper headlines. Short, descriptive, sufficient to convey the necessary information and for that reason given latitude with respect to grammar.

Comment: Another thing you'll notice is that these descriptive subtitles do not follow a consistent syntactical or structural pattern. Some (like "engine turns over" are stripped-down complete sentences; others (like "music playing") are fragments. Evidently, movie studios make no systematic effort to enforce a consistent approach to descriptive subtitles. In contrast, editors at many print publication impose a consistent structure—all complete sentences ["engine turns over"; "music plays"], say, or all fragments with particular parallel features—on subheads within a particular article or chapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brevity...

They are of minor importance, simply scene-setting or context and are not intended to be spoken.

If they were spelled out, with full grammatical accuracy [I think] they could distract from the main task - following the plot.